# Unable to configure SQL Server log shipping, latch error

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, log-shipping

SQL 2008 R2, SP1 CU8 both servers, next to each other in the rack, ~10 small databases (total under 50GB). I found that log shipping was broken (for a long time), rebooted secondary as a troubleshooting step. Tried to setup the log shipping again(via GUI) but keep running into timeouts or the following error during the "saving secondary destination configuration" step, please advise. Small shop, I'm the accidental DBA. :)

Primary SQL server's Backup jobs are all running fine. DBs are in full recovery. Tried a full backup and manual restore on the secondary then resetting up log shipping, that doesn't work either. I don't know if I have some other larger problem going on. general application/DB performance seems to be ok from what I can tell.

===================================

SQL Server Management Studio could not save the configuration of 'SQL_SecondaryServer' as a Secondary. (Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio)

===================================

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

---

Program Location:

at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String sqlCommand, ExecutionTypes executionType)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String sqlCommand)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.LogShippingSecondaryServer.Save(LogShippingPrimaryServer curPrimaryServer, LogShippingMonitorServer curMonitorServer, ServerConnection serverRemoteConn)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.LogShippingPropertyControl.PersistChange4()

===================================

Time-out occurred while waiting for buffer latch type 2 for page (1:47443), database ID 4. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

---

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.50.4290&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=845&LinkId=20476

---

Server Name: SQL_SecondaryServer
Error Number: 845
Severity: 17
State: 1
Procedure: sp_MSprocesslogshippingmonitorsecondary
Line Number: 58

---

Program Location:

at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager.ExecuteTSql(ExecuteTSqlAction action, Object execObject, DataSet fillDataSet, Boolean catchException)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String sqlCommand, ExecutionTypes executionType)